# Revert back to the previous dev version of a module using composer

Tags: 8, drush, composer

Current last dev release of the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module for drupal 8 was out on (29 Mar 2019).
However, I need to download the **previous** dev version before the dev version release mentioned above.

The last dev release was out on (29 Mar 2019)

but I need the previous dev version which was out on (10 May 2017)

It is important for me to record this specific dev version in composer.json file so the same dev version of the module will be used on all environments.

How can I do that ?

**Note:** i can use any of Composer, Git or Drush commands.

Comment: Do you really want a version of that module from 2 years and many major Drupal versions ago?

Comment: @Kevin yes because the last dev version for my requirements is broken and it seems the maintainer doesn't have enough time for it anymore.... so I have to go back to the previous version until the last is fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to refer to the dev branch and reference the SHA of the version of dev you want in Composer.

Example:

`composer require drupal/field_group:3.x-dev#COMMITSHA`

This will fetch the dev branch of version 8.x-3.x at this specific commit. To get that commit itself, you’ll have to find it on the git page for the project ( which now goes to GitLab).

I can’t find the exact one you are looking for (I’m on mobile) but here is an example.

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_group/commit/a4bd38698187c30184d5c76fd884be86e2091fe7

So you’d do:

`composer require drupal/field_group:3.x-dev#a4bd3869`

Comment: I think it's also a best practice to always wrap the package in quotes like so: `composer require 'drupal/field_group:3.x-dev#a4bd3869'`

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for the reply and help,,, but I am unable to find the the #CommitSHA of the dev version released just before the latest dev release (on 10 May 2017)

Comment: You have to look through the commit history to find it.

Comment: Finally I have found it and `composer require 'drupal/field_group:3.x-dev'#2e8c7106` has fixed the issue.... thank you so much for your help @Kevin